# Gradient overlays over text

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I was trying to implement gradient effect to an image (which I did), but it also covers my text. I cannot figure out where I need to change the code, so the text does not get covered by gradient effect. Can somebody please explain or provide links to the necessary information I need to read?

Thank you!

[Screenshot of web page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PoQU5.jpg)

```
<div class="page-header header-filter">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 ml-auto mr-auto">
                <div class="brand">
                    <h1> Some smart text </h1>
                    <h3 class="title"> Start the Development With A Badass Bootstrap 4 UI Kit inspired by Material Design. </h3>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>

.page-header {
height: 100vh;
color: #fff;
background-position: 50%;
background-size: cover;
background-image: url(../img/ggg.jpg);
display: flex;
align-items: center;
}

.brand {
    text-align: center;
}

.header-filter::after {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    content: "";
}

.header-filter::after {
    background: rgba(132,13,121,.88);
    background: linear-gradient(45deg,rgba(132,13,121,.88),rgba(208,44,180,.31));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(135deg,rgba(132,13,121,.88),rgba(208,44,180,.31));
}
```

Comment: can you post a sample of what you want

Comment: Yes, this version https://demos.creative-tim.com/marketplace/material-kit-pro/presentation.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`z-index: -1;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index) to  `.header-filter::after` instead  `z-index: 1;`
Also use `position:relative` to `.brand`

```css
.page-header {
height: 100vh;
color: #fff;
background-position: 50%;
background-size: cover;
background-image: url(../img/ggg.jpg);
display: flex;
align-items: center;
}

.brand {
    text-align: center;
    position:relative;
    z-index:2;
}

.header-filter::after {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    content: "";
    background: rgba(132,13,121,.88);
    background: linear-gradient(45deg,rgba(132,13,121,.88),rgba(208,44,180,.31));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(135deg,rgba(132,13,121,.88),rgba(208,44,180,.31));
    z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="page-header header-filter">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 ml-auto mr-auto">
                <div class="brand">
                    <h1> Some smart text </h1>
                    <h3 class="title"> Start the Development With A Badass Bootstrap 4 UI Kit inspired by Material Design. </h3>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: In this case, the whole effect disappers

Comment: try to set `position: relative;` instead `position: absolute;`

Comment: Gradient effect. I already tried to change z-index of different elements. I tried to change z-index of brand, header-filter , and removing it completely. It either removes gradient effect completely, or does not change anything at all

Comment: what browser do you use?

Comment: do you maen that the color of text is not white... it is white cover by graient?

Comment: https://demos.creative-tim.com/marketplace/material-kit-pro/presentation.html. I want it look like here, but gradient overlays the text which I do not wish to happen. I cannot figure out why... Thank you for your help. I'm pretty new to this, so it might be a dumb question

Comment: It is still overlayed. I insterted a background picture, https://jsfiddle.net/45dj02eg/6/

Answer (score 0):

Set your `.brand` element's `z-index` to a higher value than that of the `.header-filter` class.

Be sure also to set the `.brand` element's `position` property to relative.

See below for an example:

```css
.page-header {
  height: 100vh;
  color: #fff;
  background-position: 50%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-image: url(../img/ggg.jpg);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.brand {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

.header-filter::after {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  content: "";
}

.header-filter::after {
  background: rgba(132, 13, 121, .88);
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(132, 13, 121, .88), rgba(208, 44, 180, .31));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(132, 13, 121, .88), rgba(208, 44, 180, .31));
}

html css bootstrap-4 shareeditflag asked 49 secs ago
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="page-header header-filter">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-8 ml-auto mr-auto">
        <div class="brand">
          <h1> Some smart text </h1>
          <h3 class="title"> Start the Development With A Badass Bootstrap 4 UI Kit inspired by Material Design. </h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```